# Celery long running task state goes back to pending despite task_track_started=True

Tags: python, celery

There are a lot of similar questions, but I cannot figure out what is happening in my case.

I am using celery to queue long running tasks that have to be executed sequentially.

I launch tasks this way:

```py
task = mytask.apply_async(
   args=[myargs],
   task_id=my_custom_task_id,
   queue="gpu_queue",
)
```

I launch the worker this way:

`celery -A celery_app worker -Q gpu_queue --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=1 -E`

Inside `mytask` I regularly call `current_task.update_state(state="MYCUSTOMSTATE", meta={'customkey': 'customvalue'})`

And I try to monitor the task state with:

```
task = celery_app.AsyncResult(task_id)
task.status
task.result  # contains the the meta dict
```

Everything works fine except that as soon as there is more than one task in the queue, the running task randomly (?) reports `PENDING` as its status and an empty meta dictionnary, **even though I use `task_track_started=True`** in `celeryconfig.py`. This is very frustrating because apart from the bogus reporting, I am very happy with how this all works. Is there a fix for this? Is celery the wrong tool for the job?

The only fix I can think of is getting my monitoring app to not switch display the PENDING state when it received the info that the task already started, but this feels very hacky.

## MWE

### app.py

```
import time

from celery import Celery, current_task

app = Celery('tasks', backend='rpc://', broker='pyamqp://guest@localhost//')

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    current_task.update_state(state="Running")
    for i in range(5):
        time.sleep(1)
    return x + y
```

### watch.py

```
import time

from app import app, add

task = add.apply_async(
    args=[1, 2],
    task_id="task1",
)

print("task1 alone")

for _ in range(5):
    print("task1", app.AsyncResult("task1").status)
    time.sleep(0.5)

task = add.apply_async(
    args=[3, 4],
    task_id="task2",
)

print("task2 was launched")

while not app.AsyncResult("task2").ready():
    print("task1", app.AsyncResult("task1").status)
    print("task2", app.AsyncResult("task2").status)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

### celeryconfig.py

```
task_track_started=True
```

`docker run -p 5672:5672 rabbitmq`

`celery --config=celeryconfig -A app worker --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=1 -E`

`python watch.py`

### Output:

```
task1 alone
task1 PENDING
task1 Running
task1 Running
task1 Running
task1 Running
task2 was launched
task1 Running
task2 PENDING
task1 PENDING
task2 PENDING
task1 PENDING
task2 PENDING
task1 PENDING
task2 PENDING
task1 PENDING
task2 PENDING
task1 SUCCESS
task2 Running
task1 PENDING
task2 Running
task1 PENDING
task2 PENDING
task1 PENDING
task2 PENDING
task1 PENDING
task2 PENDING
task1 PENDING
task2 PENDING
task1 PENDING
task2 PENDING
task1 PENDING
task2 PENDING
task1 PENDING
task2 PENDING
task1 PENDING
task2 PENDING
```

Comment: Are you saying it reports STARTED state, and then PENDING? If that is the case then I would say it is a bug that should be reported, or they should update the documentation saying that Celery may report PENDING state _after_ STARTED... In your case I would expect MYCUSTOMSTATE to be reported instead of PENDING.

Comment: I don't even see the STARTED state because I poll every 1s to display the status, so I only see MYCUSTOMSTATE, then PENDING again when I launch a second task. Once in a while, I see MYCUSTOMSTATE again. But the task is definitely processing, if I just wait it finishes and then the second one starts. So this shouldn't happen you say. I have got to work on MWE to reproduce that for a bug report. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my issue by using redis as a celery backend and adding `result_persistent=True` to the conf. I am not sure if what I experienced is a bug of celery or expected behaviour with the RPC backend.